# Function does not remove second integer

Tags: python, arrays, function

```
    def sumUp(array):
        for row in array:
            if row > 5:
                array.remove(row)
        add = sum(array)
        return add
```

The array is `[1, 20, 20, 5, 50, 2, 2, 1]`

The array returned is `[1, 20, 5, 2, 2, 1]`

I was wondering where I went wrong since that 20 is still in the array.

Comment: Because you remove, so the current index became the next. So the next never checked

Comment: Thank you for the answers! They all solved my problem as well as made me understand what was wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
for row in array:
```

with

```
for row in array[:]:
```

This way you'll be iterating over a copy of the `array`, which won't be modified by your `remove`s.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because you are removing elements from the list over which you are iterating.

You can use a list comprehension to create a new list containing only the elements you don't want to remove:

```
def sumUp(array):
    array = [x for x in array if x <= 5]
    add = sum(array)
    return add
```

Comment: I am not certain if modifying the original argument was indended by the OP or if it was an unplanned side effect. Anyway, your code doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because of the way Python iterates over collections. Functionally, the construct `for value in collection` runs a *hidden* position pointer over that collection, increasing by one each time:

```
for hidden in range(0, len(collection)):
```

That means, if you delete anything in the collection at or before your current position, the next iteration will skip an element. For example, if you're at position 3:

```
      v
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
a b c d e f g
```

and you delete it, you get:

```
      v
0 1 2 3 4 5
a b c e f g
```

Then the next iteration will skip `e` altogether because it advances the pointer:

```
        v
0 1 2 3 4 5
a b c e f g
```

Now that may not be how Python works exactly under the covers but it is how it works functionally. That's why it's generally a bad idea to modify lists that you're iterating over.

In terms of a solution, it depends on whether you're trying to modify the original list or not. If you are, you can just return a tuple of the new list and the sum, with something like:

```
def sumUp(array):
    newArr = [item for item in array if item <= 5]
    return (sum(newArr), newArr)
```

and call it with:

```
(sumOfSmalls, array) = sumUp(array)
```

If you just want the sum of the specific values *without* changing the array, that's much easier:

```
def sumUp(array):
    return sum([item for item in array if item <= 5])
```

I'd even consider not making a function for that, since it's simple enough to do in the calling code.

Answer (score -1):

when you remove you are skipping the next element, so do it in reverse

```
def sumUp(array):
        for i,row in enumerate(reversed(array)):
            if row > 5:
                array.remove(row)
        print(array)
        add = sum(array)
        return add
ar = [1, 20, 20, 5, 50, 2, 2, 1]
sumUp(ar)
```

```
[1, 5, 2, 2, 1]
11
```